# How to exit android S animated splash screen only after animation finishes

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

[SplashScreen](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen#setOnExitAnimationListener(androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.OnExitAnimationListener)) API offers 2 methods but can't figure out how to do this. setKeepOnScreenCondition doesn't pass in a splashScreenView so the animation remaining time can't be checked in there.

On the other hand, setOnExitAnimationListener passes in a splashScreenView, which is only called when the splashscreen is ready to be removed. This could be too soon if the animation has not finished running but the app is ready to paint first frame.